# Delphi Component: How to use parent font?

Tags: delphi, fonts, components, delphi-5

i have a custom component that uses the `ParentFont`.

During construction of my component, i can see that initially the component's font is set to the default `MS Sans Serif`:

```
constructor TCustomWidget.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
   inherited Create(AOwner);

   ...
end;
```

Inspecting shows `Self.Font.Name: 'MS Sans Serif'`

Some time later, the font of my component is updated to reflect the parent's font:

```
TReader.ReadComponent(nil)
   SetCompName
      TControl.SetParentComponent
         TControl.SetParent
            TWinControl.InsertControl
               AControl.Perform(CM_PARENTFONTCHANGED, 0, 0);
```

And after that everything is great, my component's font has been changed to the parent's font (e.g. `MS Shell Dlg 2').

The problem is that my child controls are not keeping in sync with their parent's font (i.e. my component).

During my components constructor, i create child controls:

```
constructor TCustomWidget.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
   inherited Create(AOwner);

   ...
   CreateComponents;
end;

procedure TCustomWidget.CreateComponents;
begin
   ...
   FpnlBottom := TPanel.Create(Self);
   FpnlBottom.Caption := '';
   FpnlBottom.Parent := Self;
   FpnlBottom.Align := alBottom;
   FpnlBottom.Height := 46;
   FpnlBottom.ParentFont := True;
   ...
end;
```

And initially my `FpnlBottom` has the default font also `MS Sans Serif`.

Later, when the font of my component has been updated to **its** parent's font (e.g. `MS Shell Dlg 2`), the child controls are not having their fonts updated, and are remaining `MS Sans Serif`.

- Why are my child control's `ParentFont` property not being honored?
- How do i make my child control's `ParentFont` property work?

---

### Sample Code

Tool two hours to trim it down to manageable, reproducible, code:

```
unit WinControl1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls;

type
    TWidget = class(TWinControl)
    private
        FTitleLabel: Tlabel;
        FpnlBottom: TPanel;

        procedure CreateComponents;
    protected
        procedure FontChange(Sender: TObject);
    public
        constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    published
        {Inherited from TWinControl}
        property Align;
        property Font;
        property ParentFont;
    end;

    procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
    RegisterComponents('Samples',[TWidget]);
end;

{ TCustomWidget }

constructor TWidget.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
    inherited Create(AOwner);

    ControlStyle := ControlStyle + [csAcceptsControls, csNoDesignVisible];

    Self.Width := 384;
    Self.Height := 240;

    Self.Font.OnChange := FontChange;

    CreateComponents;
end;

procedure TWidget.CreateComponents;
begin
    FpnlBottom := TPanel.Create(Self);
    FpnlBottom.Parent := Self;
    FpnlBottom.Align := alBottom;
    FpnlBottom.Color := clWindow;
    FpnlBottom.Caption := 'FpnlBottom';
    FpnlBottom.Height := 45;

    FTitleLabel := TLabel.Create(Self);
    FTitleLabel.Parent := FpnlBottom;
    FTitleLabel.Left := 11;
    FTitleLabel.Top := 11;
    FTitleLabel.Caption := 'Hello, world!';
    FTitleLabel.AutoSize := True;
    FTitleLabel.Font.Color := $00993300;
    FTitleLabel.Font.Size := Self.Font.Size+3;
    FTitleLabel.ParentFont := False;
end;

procedure TWidget.FontChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
    //title label is always 3 points larger than the rest of the content
    FTitleLabel.Font.Name := Self.Font.Name;
    FTitleLabel.Font.Size := Self.Font.Size+3;

    OutputDebugString(PChar('New font '+Self.Font.Name));
end;

end.
```

Comment: All my controls use the font of their parent. That's clearly how it is meant to work. Why do your controls misbehave? I don't know. Perhaps a minimal reproduction of the fault would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After seeing your sample code, you are using the `FontChange` event handler all wrong. You should not be using it at all.  You are bypassing the native `TControl.FontChanged()` event handler, which triggers `CM_FONTCHANGED` and `CM_PARENTFONTCHANGED` notifications, so you are actually breaking the `ParentFont` logic.  Just get rid of your `TWidget.FontChanged()` event handler altogether.  If you need to react to changed to your component's `Font` property, you need to intercept the `CM_FONTCHANGED` message instead, eg:

```
unit WinControl1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls;

type
  TWidget = class(TWinControl)
  private
    FTitleLabel: TLabel;
    FpnlBottom: TPanel;
    procedure CreateComponents;
    procedure CMFontChanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_FONTCHANGED;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    {Inherited from TWinControl}
    property Align;
    property Font;
    property ParentFont;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples',[TWidget]);
end;

{ TCustomWidget }

constructor TWidget.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ControlStyle := ControlStyle + [csAcceptsControls, csNoDesignVisible];
  Self.Width := 384;
  Self.Height := 240;
  CreateComponents;
end;

procedure TWidget.CreateComponents;
begin
  FpnlBottom := TPanel.Create(Self);
  FpnlBottom.Parent := Self;
  FpnlBottom.Align := alBottom;
  FpnlBottom.Color := clWindow;
  FpnlBottom.Caption := 'FpnlBottom';
  FpnlBottom.Height := 45;

  FTitleLabel := TLabel.Create(Self);
  FTitleLabel.Parent := FpnlBottom;
  FTitleLabel.Left := 11;
  FTitleLabel.Top := 11;
  FTitleLabel.Caption := 'Hello, world!';
  FTitleLabel.AutoSize := True;
  FTitleLabel.Font.Color := $00993300;
  FTitleLabel.Font.Size := Self.Font.Size+3;
  FTitleLabel.ParentFont := False;
end;

procedure TWidget.CMFontChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited; // let TControl and TWinControl react first
  //title label is always 3 points larger than the rest of the content
  FTitleLabel.Font.Name := Self.Font.Name;
  FTitleLabel.Font.Size := Self.Font.Size + 3;
  OutputDebugString(PChar('New font ' + Self.Font.Name));
end;

end.
```

Comment: +1 Surely you don't even need to handle `CMFontChanged` in this case because you set it all in `CreateComponents`.

Comment: Yes, `CM_FONTCHANGED` needs to be handled, because of Ian's "title label is always 3 points larger than the rest of the content" requirement. If TWidget's `Font.Size` is changed after it is initially set, the `FTitleLabel.Font.Size` value would fall out of sync without `CM_FONTCHANGED` being handled.

Comment: Wow. i never would have guessed that the VCL infrastructure silently takes over an `OnChange` event, rather than using an internal mechanism. But looks like you right. +1 and accepted.

Comment: Classes like `TFont`, `TPen`, `TBrush`, etc are standalone utility classes. `TControl` has to assign its own internal `OnChange` event handler to respond to changes to its `Font` property.  You were replacing that internal event handler with your own.

Answer (score 4):

Every time your component's `Font` property is updated, the component automatically sends `CM_PARENTFONTCHANGED` messages to each of its child controls, at which time each control checks whether its `ParentFont` property is True or not.  Have you checked to make sure your child control's `ParentFont` properties are still set to True?  Perhaps during their own DFM streaming, the child controls are setting their `Font` properties, which wouuld reset the `ParentFont` to False.

Comment: And +1, this is useful. Sometimes tracing through the (undocumented) flow of information up and down control hierarchies is difficult.